# How to put placemark.locality in my weather API?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, core-location

I am working on an app that gets your current location and then gives you the present weather conditions in your location (City).

The app works successfully but only when I select which city the API should generate weather conditions for.

I am able to get the users current city in the placemark.count, but i have not been able to put the placemark.count in my weather API url.

Here is my full code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    @IBOutlet weak var valueLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var temperature: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var temperatureImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cityLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var maxTemp: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var minTemp: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var sunriseLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var sunsetLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var moonriseLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var moonsetLabel: UILabel!

    func clock() {
        let date = NSDate()
        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute | .CalendarUnitSecond, fromDate: date)
        var hour = components.hour > 12 ? components.hour - 12 : components.hour

        hour = hour == 0 ? 12 : hour

        let hourString = hour > 9 ? "\(hour)" : "0\(hour)"
        let minutes = components.minute > 9 ? "\(components.minute)" : "0\(components.minute)"
        let seconds = components.second > 9 ? "\(components.second)" : "0\(components.second)"
        let am = components.hour > 12 ? "PM" : "AM"

        timeLabel.text = "\(hourString):\(minutes):\(seconds) \(am)"

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            if placemarks.count > 0 {
                let pm = placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark
                self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
            }
        })
    }

    func displayLocationInfo(placemark: CLPlacemark) {
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        println(placemark.locality)
        println(placemark.postalCode)
        println(placemark.administrativeArea)
        println(placemark.country)
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
        println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }

    override  func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        var array : NSArray
        var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector ("clock") , userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        timeLabel.text = ""
        self.timeLabel.alpha = 0

        temperature.text = ""
        self.temperature.alpha = 0

        maxTemp.text = ""
        self.maxTemp.alpha = -1

        minTemp.text = ""
        self.minTemp.alpha = 0

        sunriseLabel.text = ""
        self.sunriseLabel.alpha = 0

        sunsetLabel.text = ""
        self.sunsetLabel.alpha = 0

        moonriseLabel.text = ""
        self.moonriseLabel.alpha = 0
        moonsetLabel.text = ""
        self.moonsetLabel.alpha = 0

        self.temperatureImage.alpha = 0
        self.valueLabel.alpha = 0

        var myvariableOne = ""

        //myvariable = myvariableOne

        var key = “**mykey**"
        var urladd1 = "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v2/weather.ashx?q="
        var urlString2 = "Lagos"
        var urlString3 = "&format=json&num_of_days=1&key="
        var urlString = urladd1 + urlString2 + urlString3 + key

        println(urlString)

        cityLabel.text = urlString2
        self.cityLabel.alpha = 0

        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                println(error)
            } else {
                // weather info loading
                let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSDictionary
                let mainObject: NSDictionary = jsonResult.objectForKey("data") as! NSDictionary
                print(mainObject)

                let currentConditions: NSArray = mainObject.objectForKey("current_condition") as! NSArray
                let icon: NSArray = currentConditions[0]["weatherIconUrl"] as! NSArray
                let iconPath: AnyObject? = icon[0]["value"]
                let iconRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "\(iconPath!)")!)

                var image: UIImage?

                NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(iconRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: { ( response: NSURLResponse!, imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                    self.temperatureImage.image = image
                })

                let currentTemperature: AnyObject? = currentConditions[0]["temp_C"]
                self.temperature.text = "\(currentTemperature!) ℃"
                let weather: NSArray = mainObject.objectForKey("weather") as! NSArray
                let weatherDictionary: NSDictionary = weather.objectAtIndex(0) as! NSDictionary
                let astronomyArray: NSArray = weatherDictionary.objectForKey("astronomy") as! NSArray
                let moonriseTime: AnyObject? = astronomyArray[0]["moonrise"]

                self.moonriseLabel.text = "\(moonriseTime!)"
                let moonsetTime: AnyObject? = astronomyArray[0]["moonset"]
                self.moonsetLabel.text = "\(moonsetTime!)"
                let sunriseTime: AnyObject? = astronomyArray[0]["sunrise"]
                self.sunriseLabel.text = "\(sunriseTime!)"
                let sunsetTime : AnyObject? = astronomyArray[0]["sunset"]
                self.sunsetLabel.text = "\(sunsetTime!)"
                let maxTemp: AnyObject? = weatherDictionary.objectForKey("maxtempC")
                self.maxTemp.text = "\(maxTemp!) ℃"
                let minTemp: AnyObject? = weatherDictionary.objectForKey("mintempC")
                self.minTemp.text = "\(minTemp!) ℃"
            }
        })

        task.resume()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(5.0, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.timeLabel.alpha = 2.0
            self.temperature.alpha = 5.0
            self.maxTemp.alpha = 2.0
            self.minTemp.alpha = 2.0
            self.sunriseLabel.alpha = 2.0
            self.sunsetLabel.alpha = 2.0
            self.moonriseLabel.alpha = 2.0
            self.moonsetLabel.alpha = 2.0
            self.cityLabel.alpha = 2.0
            self.temperatureImage.alpha = 5.0
            self.valueLabel.alpha = 5.0
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry my code got a bit scattered there but that's all the code. The complete Url String I want to put it in is the variable "urlString" in the viewDidLoad().  Also note that "**Mykey***" is my private API key that I wish not to disclose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the following course of action:

First create a function that will handle all your request, you can pass the city you want as an argument:

```
func getWeatherFromCity(city: String) {
        var key = “**mykey**"
        var urladd1 = "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v2/weather.ashx?q="
        var urlString2 = city
        var urlString3 = "&format=json&num_of_days=1&key="
        var urlString = urladd1 + urlString2 + urlString3 + key

        println(urlString)

        cityLabel.text = urlString2
        self.cityLabel.alpha = 0

        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                println(error)
            } else {
                // weather info loading
                let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSDictionary
                let mainObject: NSDictionary = jsonResult.objectForKey("data") as! NSDictionary
                print(mainObject)

                let currentConditions: NSArray = mainObject.objectForKey("current_condition") as! NSArray
                let icon: NSArray = currentConditions[0]["weatherIconUrl"] as! NSArray
                let iconPath: AnyObject? = icon[0]["value"]
                let iconRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "\(iconPath!)")!)

                var image: UIImage?

                NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(iconRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: { ( response: NSURLResponse!, imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                    self.temperatureImage.image = image
                })

                let currentTemperature: AnyObject? = currentConditions[0]["temp_C"]
                self.temperature.text = "\(currentTemperature!) ℃"
                let weather: NSArray = mainObject.objectForKey("weather") as! NSArray
                let weatherDictionary: NSDictionary = weather.objectAtIndex(0) as! NSDictionary
                let astronomyArray: NSArray = weatherDictionary.objectForKey("astronomy") as! NSArray
                let moonriseTime: AnyObject? = astronomyArray[0]["moonrise"]

                self.moonriseLabel.text = "\(moonriseTime!)"
                let moonsetTime: AnyObject? = astronomyArray[0]["moonset"]
                self.moonsetLabel.text = "\(moonsetTime!)"
                let sunriseTime: AnyObject? = astronomyArray[0]["sunrise"]
                self.sunriseLabel.text = "\(sunriseTime!)"
                let sunsetTime : AnyObject? = astronomyArray[0]["sunset"]
                self.sunsetLabel.text = "\(sunsetTime!)"
                let maxTemp: AnyObject? = weatherDictionary.objectForKey("maxtempC")
                self.maxTemp.text = "\(maxTemp!) ℃"
                let minTemp: AnyObject? = weatherDictionary.objectForKey("mintempC")
                self.minTemp.text = "\(minTemp!) ℃"
            }
        })

        task.resume()
}
```

In your `viewDidLoad` you can call this function with "Lagos as an argument

```
override  func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
    getWeatherFromCity("Lagos)
}
```

finally in your `locationManager(_ didUpdateLocations locations: _)`, you can call this same function when you have received your location:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            if placemarks.count > 0 {
                let pm = placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark
                self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
                getWeatherFromCity(pm.locality)
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying but you still did not tell me how to pass in the city I got from the locationManager function into the variable titled urlString2 so it will complete the variable urlString and generate the weather for that city from the API. For example if the locationManager generates a city called New York in the placemark.locality. If i pass in New York into urlString2, the urlString will now become http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v2/weather.ashx?q=NEWYORK&format=json&num_of_days=1&key=**mykey** . This url will generate the weather conditions for New York. Thank you.

Comment: I edited my answer to answer this problem. In your function you have have to assign the parameter to urlString2 like that: var urlString2 = city

Comment: I haven't tried out this code yet but I'm sure it will work based on my analysis. Thanks. Is there anyway I can connect with you? I see we both program iOS apps as a hobby. Thanks

Comment: Feel free to contact me on Twitter, username in profile

Comment: I just followed you on twitter.